# Out of curiosity, is it possible to initialize a 0-by-1 array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, empty-list

In Java, you can instantiate the following:

1-by-1 array: `int[][] arr = {{0}};`

1-by-0 array: `int[][] arr = {{}};`

0-by-0 array: `int[][] arr = {};`

Is a 0-by-1 array possible?

Comment: To me, it wouldn't make sense. The inner array would be inside a row that doesn't exist.

Comment: I guess you get both 0x1 and 1x0 by `{{}}`.

Comment: Does `int[][] arr = new int[0][1];` compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java doesn't know multidimensional arrays, it does only know arrays which can contain other arrays, thus the result doesn't even have to be "rectangular" - the content arrays are independent of each other.

So a 0-length "outer" array can't contain any inner array of length "1".

Answer (score 0):

A zero length array is an empty array.
It doesn't contain anything, so it can't contain a 1 element array.